# Combinatorics and arrangement of letters in the alphabet

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If the letters A, B, C, D and E are lined up in a random order, what is the probability that

(a) there are less than 2 letters in-between A and B;

(b) there is not exactly one letter between A and B.

For both parts, I get the answer as 0.7, can please someone confirm whether this is correct (especially for part (b))? Many thanks.

Comment: Both numbers are correct. I can't guarantee that you calculated them correctly, but the result is correct.

Comment: Thank you. It was part of an online multiple choice exam which said one of the two was not correct, but it didn't indicate which one.

Comment: Well I see 84 possibilities for (a): the A and B can be in locations (1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (3,5) or (4,5). Each of these positions has 2 options for the ordering of $AB$ and $3!=6$ options for the other letters. This yields $7\cdot 2\cdot 6=84$ options out of $5!$ in total, and $\frac{84}{5!}=0.7$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Do you also get 0.7 for (b)?

Comment: For (b), the inverse is easier to calculate. I.e. There IS exactly one letter between A and B, so you get (1,3), (2,4) and (3,5) as possible positions for A and B, meaning $3\cdot 2\cdot 6=36$ total options for a probability of $\frac{36}{5!}=0.3$, so the probability of NOT eaxctly one letter is $1-0.3=0.7$.

Comment: Thank you. We have the same methods, just nice to know I've not done something completely wrong. I'll ask my professor about it later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46785/discussion-between-wrb98-and-5xum).